# Rails token authentication from angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, angularjs

I've developed an API with rails-api.

To implement te API authentication I've followed the railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api.

In the example it uses `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` from `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods` to check the existence of an authentication token.

What I don't know how to do is sending this token from Angular to the API. Do I have to put it in a header? what header? does it have to be encoded in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution:

- The token has to be sent like this `var authorizationHeader = 'Token token="' + token + '"'`
- That string has to be set in the `AUTHORIZATION` header.